# How to adjust my listview in ios Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have a problem in my `ListView` on iOS. I can't adjust it to all iOS templates, ex: put `HeightRequest = "855"` on my iPhone 7 it already fits correctly, else on the iPhone 5 and smaller my `ListView` from a scrow. so I want my `ListView` to automatically adjust to the screen size.

```
  <ListView x:Name="listView"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            ItemsSource="{Binding FeedItems}"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" HeightRequest="855">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="5">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackLayout HeightRequest = "60" WidthRequest="60">
                                <Image x:Name="Image"  Source="{Binding Image}" Scale="1.0" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                         </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Spacing="4"  VerticalOptions="Center">
                               <Label Text="{Binding Category}" TextColor="White"  FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" BackgroundColor="{Binding Color_category}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding PublishDate}" TextColor="#666666" FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="#234084" Font="Bold" FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Don't use the `HeightRequest` for that use the `VerticallOptions="FillAndExpand"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand a little more.

`HeightRequest` is used when you want to define a fixed size to an element. Xamarin will make its best to fulfill with this. In the other hand when you want your size to be relative you use the `VerticalOptions` and `HorizontalOptions`. This two properties will take a [LayoutOptions](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions/) struct and the default value for this is Fill (without expand).

This struct has two sets of properties, the ones I call "regular"

- Center
- Start
- End
- Fll

And the ones that "expands"

- CenterAndExpand
- StartAndExpand
- EndAndExpand
- FillAndExpand

You can read more about these [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options/).

This last one `FillAndExpand` will take all the available space in the orientation it's used. This is the one you should use in your `ListView` to make it as big as the screen

Hope this helps.-